# How to use Python to create a Post in Wordpress?

Tags: rest-api, wp-api

I found the API reference here: https://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/

Based on the API reference above, I wrote this Python code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from datetime import datetime

import json

def create(wordpressUrl, content):

    params = {
        'date_gmt': datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + "Z",
        'status': 'publish',
        'title': 'The Title',
        'author': 'The Author',
        'content': content
    }
    postparam = json.dumps(params).encode('utf-8')
    req = Request(wordpressUrl + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", method='POST', data=postparam)
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    r = urlopen(req)

    if(r.getcode() != 200):
        raise Exception("failed with rc=" + r.getcode())

    return json.loads(r.read())
```

Why when calling this code, the WP API just returns the site's About page, and does not create a new Post? How else can I create a Post inside of Wordpress, using Python to call the WP API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as `@prathamesh patil` say, you missed the `authentication` = `your jwt token`

#### how to generate `jwt token` ?

- simple = core logic

  - install and enable WordPress plugin:  [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)
  - wordpress server enable `HTTP:Authorization`

    - purpose: allow to call `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1` api
  - add `JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY` into `wp-config.php`
  - call `POST https://www.yourWebsite.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` with wordpress `username` and `password`, response contain your expected **jwt token**

    - look like: `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvd3d3LmNyaWZhbi5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1ODQxMDk4OTAsIm5iZiI6MTU4NDEwOTg5MCwiZXhwIjoxNTg0NzE0NjkwLCJkYXRhIjp7InVzZXIiOnsiaWQiOiIxIn19fQ.YvFzitTfIZaCwtkxKTIjP715795OMAVQowgnD8G3wk0`
- detail

  - please refer my answer for another post:

    - [Publish WordPress Post with Python Requests and REST API - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532738/publish-wordpress-post-with-python-requests-and-rest-api/65547860#65547860)

### python code to call wordpress REST api to create posts

code:

```python
    def createPost(self,
            title,
            content,
            dateStr,
            slug,
            categoryNameList=[],
            tagNameList=[],
            status="draft",
            postFormat="standard"
        ):
        """Create wordpress standard post
            by call REST api: POST /wp-json/wp/v2/posts

        Args:
            title (str): post title
            content (str): post content of html
            dateStr (str): date string
            slug (str): post slug url
            categoryNameList (list): category name list
            tagNameList (list): tag name list
            status (str): status, default to 'draft'
            postFormat (str): post format, default to 'standard'
        Returns:
            (bool, dict)
                True, uploaded post info
                False, error detail
        Raises:
        """
        curHeaders = {
            "Authorization": self.authorization,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
        }
        logging.debug("curHeaders=%s", curHeaders)

        categoryIdList = []
        tagIdList = []

        if categoryNameList:
            # ['Mac']
            categoryIdList = self.getTaxonomyIdList(categoryNameList, taxonomy="category")
            # category nameList=['Mac'] -> taxonomyIdList=[1374]

        if tagNameList:
            # ['切换', 'GPU', 'pmset', '显卡模式']
            tagIdList = self.getTaxonomyIdList(tagNameList, taxonomy="post_tag")
            # post_tag nameList=['切换', 'GPU', 'pmset', '显卡模式'] -> taxonomyIdList=[1367, 13224, 13225, 13226]

        postDict = {
            "title": title, # '【记录】Mac中用pmset设置GPU显卡切换模式'
            "content": content, # '<html>\n <div>\n  折腾：\n </div>\n <div>\n  【已解决】Mac Pro 2018款发热量大很烫非常烫\n </div>\n <div>\n  期间，...performance graphic cards\n    </li>\n   </ul>\n  </ul>\n </ul>\n <div>\n  <br/>\n </div>\n</html>'
            # "date_gmt": dateStr,
            "date": dateStr, # '2020-08-17T10:16:34'
            "slug": slug, # 'on_mac_pmset_is_used_set_gpu_graphics_card_switching_mode'
            "status": status, # 'draft'
            "format": postFormat, # 'standard'
            "categories": categoryIdList, # [1374]
            "tags": tagIdList, # [1367, 13224, 13225, 13226]
            # TODO: featured_media, excerpt
        }
        logging.debug("postDict=%s", postDict)
        # postDict={'title': '【记录】Mac中用pmset设置GPU显卡切换模式', 'content': '<html>\n <div>\n  折腾：\n </div>\n <div>\。。。。<br/>\n </div>\n</html>', 'date': '2020-08-17T10:16:34', 'slug': 'on_mac_pmset_is_used_set_gpu_graphics_card_switching_mode', 'status': 'draft', 'format': 'standard', 'categories': [1374], 'tags': [1367, 13224, 13225, 13226]}
        createPostUrl = self.apiPosts
        resp = requests.post(
            createPostUrl,
            proxies=self.requestsProxies,
            headers=curHeaders,
            # data=json.dumps(postDict),
            json=postDict, # internal auto do json.dumps
        )
        logging.info("createPostUrl=%s -> resp=%s", createPostUrl, resp)

        isUploadOk, respInfo = crifanWordpress.processCommonResponse(resp)
        return isUploadOk, respInfo
```

- full & latest code please refer:

  - `createPost` in [crifanWordpress.py](https://github.com/crifan/crifanLibPython/blob/master/python3/crifanLib/thirdParty/crifanWordpress.py)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing out on the authentication part , check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532738/publish-wordpress-post-with-python-requests-and-rest-api